# Joomla! 3.0 2fa 'authentication' via widget

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, two-factor-authentication

Hello I am developing a two factor authentication plugin for Joomla!. I'm stuck at a certain point because the joomla framework works in a strange way.

I want the user to use a js 2fa widget I created. When the steps in the widget are succesfully completed the joomla plugin should set the result as followed:

```
$response->status        = JAuthentication::STATUS_SUCCESS;
```

Only I can't seem to call the widget with the folowing method:

```
JFactory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration('/*set and call widget*/');
```

Because the onVerification() method is only called when the login button is already pressed. At this moment the framework already expects the plugin to know  whether the login was succesfull or not.

**Other sollution:**

What if:
I make a new module without the 2fa field. And a 2fa plugin.
The 2fa plugin is automatically called when logging in.

Steps:

```
    When the login button is clicked the credentials get verified.
    If correct.             If Not
        ↓              ↓
    The widget shows.       X Error shows.
        ↓
    Widget session gets filled in in the 2fa field
    (username & pw are also (still) filled in.
        ↓
    2FA plugin checks the widget result 
    If it is success.(logged in)    If not
        ↓              ↓
    X The user is logged in.       X Error shows
```

X = end of process.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When a user selects and sets up a 2fa a 3rd input (secret key) is shown on the default login module and that is passed to an authentication plugins onUserTwofactorAuthenticate method. If you have a completely different authentication setup (ie your widget) then that would need to be displayed through a module, not a plugin.

Comment: That i figured out. But still the validation of the STATUS_SUCCES does not wait on user input. Because of the dynamical invocation.